# MFC: debug assertion failed?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

When I run the program in debug mode, I receive this error.

```
Debug Assertion Failed!
Program: ...
File: f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\winhand.cpp
Line: 139
...
```

And it comes from the following code.

```
CObject* CHandleMap::FromHandle(HANDLE h)
{
    ASSERT(m_pClass != NULL);
    ASSERT(m_nHandles == 1 || m_nHandles == 2);

    if (h == NULL)
        return NULL;

    CObject* pObject = LookupPermanent(h);
    if (pObject != NULL)
        return pObject;   // return permanent one
    else if ((pObject = LookupTemporary(h)) != NULL)
    {
        HANDLE* ph = (HANDLE*)((BYTE*)pObject + m_nOffset);
        ASSERT(ph[0] == h || ph[0] == NULL);
```

But I am not able to tell what error it is and how to fix.

I have the following call within "CMyDialog::OnInitDialog()" which causes the failure.

```
BOOL CMyDialog::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();

    // TODO:  Add extra initialization here
    set_font_weight(IDC_STATIC1_LABEL, FW_BOLD | FW_BLACK);
    SetDlgItemText(IDC_STATIC1, L"");
```

Is it a problem doing these within OnInitDialog? Most specifically, it is "set_font_weight" that causes problem (GetFont()).

```
void CMyDialog::set_font_weight(int nID, LONG weight)
{
    CWnd *pwnd = GetDlgItem(nID);
    CFont *pfont = pwnd->GetFont();
    LOGFONT lf;
    pfont->GetLogFont(&lf);
    lf.lfWeight = weight;
    pfont->CreateFontIndirect(&lf);
    pwnd->SetFont(pfont);
}
```

Comment: If you break on it in the debugger you should be able to inspect the values and see *what* triggers the assertion. *Why* that happens, however, can't be guessed without an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I include more info, please check. Thank you.

Comment: There are three assertions in that code. The debugger should tell you which of the assertions is failing.

Comment: You need to look at the call stack and possibly show it to us.